# Using IE in a virtualbox instance to test a site in VS2015 on my workstation

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-8, visual-studio-2015, virtualbox

I have an ASP.net MVC application that I've developed using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise that is not behaving nicely in IE8, and as much as I'd like to just declare IE8 as unsupported, this is unfeasible from a business perspective at the moment.

So, to test in IE8, I downloaded a VirtualBox containing an instance of windows with IE8 from [here](https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/).

I've been successful in using this instance of IE8 to connect my organization's dev server (which is running Windows Server 2012r2, IIS 8.5.9600), so I've been able to reproduce the issue. I'd really like to be able to step through what's happening in the debugger, though.

So, I believe I have two options.

1. **Connect to the IIS instance on our dev server using Visual Studio's remote debugging feature.**
   This is kind of intimidating to me to attempt, because there seem to be a lot of options and I'm unsure how to proceed. It would be nice to be able to figure this out, though, as being able to do remote debugging on the dev server would be very helpful for future development. I tried using the default transport and putting the host for the dev sever in the "qualifier" box in VS, but it just told me the debugger service wasn't running on the remote machine, even though I'm fairly certain it is.
2. **Connect to my local workstation running Visual Studio from virtualbox**
   This seems like it would be the simplest solution, but I can't figure it out. I tried a few different network modes from virtualbox -- NAT, bridged, and Host-Only, but I could never get the page to load in IE inside the virtualbox. I tried using the ip of my workstation as reported by ipconfig /all (the IP of the normal network adapter for bridged and NAT mode, and the IP of the "Host Only" special adapter in Host Only mode) and the port VS was configured to use. No dice.

Any ideas on how I can move forward with either of these options? Or some third, better option?